# Need help to ID and remove electric outlet cover

Tags: electrical, receptacle, kitchens

I Need some help identifying and removing an electrical outlet cover in the kitchen.

I removed the middle screw but the cover is still not coming off, no screws on the sides either.

[image]

Comment: Do you intend on saving this fitting ?

Comment: @Criggie I hope not!

Comment: @dai in that case, a second plan might be to reconstruct it from the outside-in.  Drill a hole in the meat of it and screw in a large self tapping screw/lag bolt. and pull it off the wall with that ?

Comment: Prying from opposite sides at the same time would be a lot less mess and as (or more) likely to work. Drill holes in it and you're likely to be pulling shards of it out of the receptacle it's plugged into - or you'll drill that full of holes too.

Comment: the power bar might be attached to the tiles with double-sided tape ..... cut the tape by slipping a box-cutter blade between it and the wall

Comment: It's a plug-in extender/expander.  Behind it is a regular duplex outlet.  Remove the center screw and then pry it out.  It's possible that corrosion is bad or that the underlying socket is not well-anchored, so it's probably best to shut off the circuit if you have to use more than moderate prying force.

Comment: It might be that the tiles were added AFTER the socket in which case you may need to carefully chisel out the mortar around the socket

Comment: THAT is the answer, @ConanTheGerbil. This thing ain't coming out w/o a hammer. I'd leave the grout alone until I mutilated the device enough to pull the pieces *of the device* out; the grout can probably stay, and you prob want it to.

Answer (score 17):

Loosen the center screw and then pull (or pry if it's stuck) around the edges.  These plug into both outlets and can be fairly tight.

I recommend you shut off power at the service panel before trying this for safety.

Comment: Was going to use an hammer and chisel, but wanted some perspective.  its really tightly fixed

Comment: @DIYonlyonWeekends  Avoid hammers and chisels around electrical outlets. stay safe out there.

Comment: Given the tiling around it, I wouldn't be surprised if this has been glued in place. +1 to shutting off the power before the adventure begins.

Comment: What is important to realize here is that the thing in question is NOT an outlet cover, it is an outlet multiplier - the cover plate for the duplex outlet under it is typically removed, this device plugs into both sides of that outlet, and this device's screw screws into the outlet cover plate hole underneath. When they have been in place for a while they take a LOT of force to remove, and need to be pulled pretty much straight out since you have 6 prongs of plug engaged with the outlet underneath.

Comment: Given that the tile is apparently installed against it, it may be necessary to cut or break the plastic cover of the thing to free it from the tile.  At the very least one should score around the edge with a linoleum knife or some such to attempt to break it loose.

Answer (score 5):

I would shut off the circuit, then test the sockets are all dead (test all, I'm paranoid.)

Then get cleaning with degreaser and warm water.

The upper slope especially looks like it has **caked-on grease** and oils from cooking, which will have wicked inside the fitting and "glued" the whole thing together.

It might help to use warm air from a hairdryer to soften the congealed grease too.

Comment: In a kitchen it’s possible this outlet is a split circuit, with separate breakers controlling the top and bottom rows; these *should* be tied together but may not be, So +1 for testing every outlet.

Comment: The tiles are cut around it. That means there's grout holding it in too. This is going to need to get messy real quick or you're just wasting time.

Comment: You should not apply liquids to this outlet.  Even non-water-based liquids risk dragging conductive chemicals into the outlet and causing a short or fire.  And there's no point in "cleaning" anyway -- the box you see is **plugged in** to the duplex outlet behind it, with only the single screw (plus the no-doubt corroded plugs) holding it in place.

Comment: @HotLicks fair point - time for violence I think !

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you look at the back of this guy there are two 3-prong plugs, spaced to plug into the two outlets in a standard duplex outlet.  They are installed by removing the cover plate, plugging in the extender, then inserting the center screw and screwing it into the existing outlet's cover plate screw hole.